# C# iText long paragraph in table cell overlap

Tags: c#, itext7

I an using IText version 7 on C#. I'm adding a system.data.DataTable to a iText.Layout.Element.Table.

My challenge was when the Paragraph in the cell was long, the 2nd line of the Paragraph was "overlap" with the first line.
I have try to set the Paragraph height to 12. But it still fail. May I know how to fix this?

[image]

```
public void AddByTable(DataTable dbResult)
        {
            float[] columnWidths = { 25, 3, 3, 3 };
            Table table = new Table(UnitValue.CreatePercentArray(columnWidths)).UseAllAvailableWidth();
            //add header
            table.AddCell(_AddNewParagraph("Desc", padding: 1)) ;
            table.AddCell(_AddNewParagraph("DO", padding: 1));
            table.AddCell(_AddNewParagraph("Rec", padding: 1));
            table.AddCell(_AddNewParagraph("Var", padding: 1));

            table.SetKeepWithNext(true);
            var strItemDesc="";
            foreach (DataRow row in dbResult.Rows)
            {
                strItemDesc = row["vch_desc"].ToString();
                //table.AddCell(_AddNewParagraph(strItemDesc, padding: 1,fontSize:6));
                //table.AddCell(
                //    new Paragraph(strItemDesc)
                //    .SetFixedLeading(2.0f)
                //    .SetFont(_font)
                //    .SetFontSize(6)
                //    .SetPadding(1)
                //    );

                Cell c= new Cell();
                c.Add(
                    new Paragraph(strItemDesc)
                    .SetFixedLeading(2.0f)
                    .SetFont(_font)
                    .SetFontSize(6)
                    .SetPadding(1)
                    .SetHeight(12) //this height did no solve the overflow problem.
                    );
                table.AddCell(c) ;

                table.AddCell(_AddNewParagraph(row["DOQty"].ToString(), padding: 1, fontSize: 6));
                table.AddCell(_AddNewParagraph(row["RcvQty"].ToString(), padding: 1, fontSize: 6));
                table.AddCell(_AddNewParagraph(row["VAR"].ToString(), padding: 1, fontSize: 6));
            }

            _doc.Add(table);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use

```
.SetFixedLeading(2.0f)
```

which requests exactly the behavior you see. If you don't want overlapping lines, don't fix the leading at a too small value.